# VueJS2: Should I be writting functions in data()?

Tags: vuejs2

Does writing functions, in `data` considered as a good practice? I mean not in the root component, but rather in its child components.

I was asking this because I've seen one of Vue plugin [vue-echarts](https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts#using-the-component), uses this at their README.md

```
<template>
<v-chart :options="polar"/>
</template>

<style>
/**
 * The default size is 600px×400px, for responsive charts
 * you may need to set percentage values as follows (also
 * don't forget to provide a size for the container).
 */
.echarts {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<script>
import ECharts from 'vue-echarts'
import 'echarts/lib/chart/line'
import 'echarts/lib/component/polar'

export default {
  components: {
    'v-chart': ECharts
  },
  data () {
    let data = []

    for (let i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
        let t = i / 180 * Math.PI
        let r = Math.sin(2 * t) * Math.cos(2 * t)
        data.push([r, i])
    }

    return {
      polar: {
        title: {
          text: '极坐标双数值轴'
        },
        legend: {
          data: ['line']
        },
        polar: {
          center: ['50%', '54%']
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'axis',
          axisPointer: {
            type: 'cross'
          }
        },
        angleAxis: {
          type: 'value',
          startAngle: 0
        },
        radiusAxis: {
          min: 0
        },
        series: [
          {
            coordinateSystem: 'polar',
            name: 'line',
            type: 'line',
            showSymbol: false,
            data: data
          }
        ],
        animationDuration: 2000
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If so, then when does it will be executed? After `created()` lifecycle or what?

So that's two question

1. Is it considered as best practice?
2. If so, when does it will be executed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data keywork is the memory of the component. It will allow you to store the variables you want to track inside the component, it a part of the reactivity of your component.

> If so, when does it will be executed?

It will be executed after the `beforeCreate` method and before the `created` one.

cf: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

You can format your data directly inside you data function if you want to have something specific.

The example you give from the `vue-echart` plugin is the same as

```
let data = []

for (let i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
    let t = i / 180 * Math.PI
    let r = Math.sin(2 * t) * Math.cos(2 * t)
    data.push([r, i])
}

var vm = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      a: data
    }
  }
})
```

I personally prefer to format my data inside the `created()` function after the default state of my component is created, just to keep my code simpler.

Keep in your mind that the `data` keyword can also be an simple object but it should be a function inside components to avoid them to share the same object when they are duplicated inside the same Vue instance.

There is no "best practice" for this case (I might be wrong but I never saw something about it), it's just a preference that can be different between two developers

Feel free to check https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data if you want more infos about this `data`